# Scala multivariate array sum

Tags: scala, confidence-interval

I am calculating confidence interval of some ratios using bootstrapping for multi variables, and each variable has different confidence intervals.

```
case class Limits(lowerLimit: Double, upperLimit: Double, confidenceInterval: Double)

case class CI(c85: Limits, c90: Limits, c95: Limits, c99: Limits)
```

For bootstrapping, I am running a loop for 100 times.

```
val arrCIRatio: Array[CI] = Array()
var ci85: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var ci90: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var ci95: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var ci99: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
val rg = new scala.util.Random(100)

 for(iteration <- 1 to 100){
    val i= rg.nextInt(10)      
    ci85 = getInterval(a(i), 0.85)
    ci90 = getInterval(a(i), 0.90)
    ci95 = getInterval(a(i), 0.95)
    ci99 = getInterval(a(i), 0.99)

    arrCIRatio(iteration) = new CI(ci85,ci90,ci95,ci99)
}
```

After the loop finishes, I would like to take average of each upper and lower limits inside the CI array for all the **ci85, ci89, ci95, ci99.**

I can use foldLeft to calculate the sum

```
x.foldLeft(0.0)( (x, y) => x + y.lowerLimit, x.foldLeft(0.0)( (x, y) => x + y.upperLimit
```

or in naive way:

```
var avgci85: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var avgci90: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var avgci95: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
var avgci99: Limits = new Limits(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

 for(ci <- arrCIRatio){  
    ci85 = ci.c85
    ci90 = ci.c90
    ci95 = ci.c95
    ci99 = ci.c99

    avgci85 = new Limits(avgci85.lowerLimit + ci85.lowerLimit, avgci85.upperLimit + ci85.upperLimit, 0.85) 
    avgci90 = new Limits(avgci90.lowerLimit + ci90.lowerLimit, avgci90.upperLimit + ci85.upperLimit, 0.90) 
    avgci95 = new Limits(avgci95.lowerLimit + ci95.lowerLimit, avgci95.upperLimit + ci85.upperLimit, 0.95) 
    avgci99 = new Limits(avgci99.lowerLimit + ci99.lowerLimit, avgci99.upperLimit + ci85.upperLimit, 0.99) 
}
```

But I have to do the same process for atleast 10 variables, and all the CI inside the array.
So in the end, for 1 variable it will be a 3 dimensional array of **10000 x 4 x 3**.
I don't know how to sum all the variables inside that array e.g. summing all the **lower limit** of **ci85** in the array. It would be great if someone can help with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe just create method/operator for your *CI* and *Limits* which would allow you to combine two instances? Something like that:

```
case class Limits(lowerLimit: Double, upperLimit: Double, confidenceInterval: Double) {
  // operator |+| would allow us to combine two limits
  def |+|(l: Limits): Limits = Limits(l.lowerLimit + lowerLimit, l.upperLimit + upperLimit, confidenceInterval)
 // I don't know what should be done in case of attempt of combining two limits with different confidenceInterval. 
 // Maybe it's a sign that every kind of Limits should be separate case class extending the common trait
}

object Limits {
  val Zero = new Limits(0,0,0) //zero element for convienience
}

case class CI(c85: Limits, c90: Limits, c95: Limits, c99: Limits) {
  //same operator for CI, we use |+| from Limits to combine them
  def |+|(c: CI): CI = CI(c.c85 |+| c85, c.c90 |+| c90, c.c95 |+| c95, c.c99 |+| c99)
}

object CI {
  val Zero = new CI(Limits.Zero, Limits.Zero, Limits.Zero, Limits.Zero)
}
```

Then you'd be able to fold your *CI* easily:

```
arrCIRatio.fold(CI.Zero)(_ |+| _)
```

What we did is called [monoid](https://www.trivento.io/functional-programming-in-scala-with-the-monoid/). Instead of implementing *|+|* and *Zero* inside cases classes you could implement it using typeclasses (as described in the article).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting this error, where you defining variable zero for limits: error: Limits.type does not take parameters. Can you tell me what's need to be fixed.

Comment: At which line? You're using Scala 2.11 or 2.12?

Comment: Im using 2.11. Here : val Zero = Limits(0,0,0) //zero element for convienience

Comment: You also have to put `clase class Limits` and `object Limits`  in same file. Same thing for CI.

Comment: Im using zeppelin. All are in the same block.

Comment: Can you replace it with `new Limits(0,0,0)`? And `val Zero = new CI(...` ?

Comment: That's pretty awesome solution. I would like to wait for other answers too. if no, I will accept it. Thank you again :)

Comment: If I would like to extend it for average. Would you tell me how I can do that? Thank you.

Comment: Can you just divide every sum by the number of elements for average values?

Comment: got it. I will try that. :)